# Can't convert len (x) into a usable int for string slicing?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that takes a string and prints it normally, and then in reverse, like so:

```
    string = "hello"
    mirror(string)
    'helloolleh'
```

This is the code i have so far:

```
    def mirror(x) :
        sentence = " "
        length = len(x)
        lengthstring = str(len(x))
        lengthint = int(lengthstring)
        sentence = x[lengthint, 0]
        print x + sentence
```

but it keeps saying that len (x) is a tuple and not an int and it can't be part of the string slice?

Comment: Can you show where you pass in `x`, and provide a full traceback?

Comment: General note on `python` formatting: don't add spaces before parens, and do add spaces on either side of an operator (`+`, `=`, etc...). Also it's spelled sentence, not sentance. I've fixed it above.

Comment: Another general note: len() returns an int, so there's no need to convert it to a string and back.

Comment: I'm in new zealand, where sentance = sentence.

Comment: @BenCravens: I'm in New Zealand too, and "sentance" is a misspelling.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I conflated "sentence" as "sentence." and assumed that he was telling me that it was spelled sentance and that It was spelled differently were he was from.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error I get with your code is:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in mirror
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple
```

which says nothing about `len(x)`. In fact, it is referring to the line

```
    sentence = x[lengthint, 0]
```

in which you are trying to index `x` using `lengthint, 0`. Python assumes that your use of the comma indicates you want to index `x` using the tuple `(lengthint, 0)`, which is not valid.

It seems that you are trying to use string slice syntax to reverse the string. String slice syntax uses `:`, not `,`, like this:

```
sentence = x[lengthint:0]
```

But, since `lengthint` is greater than or equal to zero, that will never produce anything other than an empty result. You need to *also* tell Python to index backwards, like this:

```
sentence = x[lengthint:0:-1]
```

This almost works. It omits the first character of your original string in the reversed copy, because `0` indicates the position *past* the end position. So you have to use the special value `None`:

```
sentence = x[lengthint:None:-1]
```

After you do that and verify that it works, you can remove the use of `lengthstring` and `lengthint` (which I presume were added in an attempt to avoid the original error):

```
sentence = x[len(x):None:-1]
```

Finally, Python lets you omit the first two slice parameters in this case, leaving just:

```
sentence = x[::-1]
```

Answer (score 6):

If your goal is to make this function work I think your approach is far too complicated. You can simple add the string to its reverse:

```
>>> def mirror(example):
...     return example + example[::-1]
... 
>>> mirror('hello')
'helloolleh'
```

Python supports stride-indexing, meaning that the `[::-1]` simply reverses the string.

Comment: In my python workbook It wanted me to do it this way, I mean clearly it's not efficient but I think It's more about learning how to use len () and stuff than making the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use ':' instead of ',' to slice string, for example

> > value = '1234'
>
> > print value[0:2]
>
> 12

In order to reverse the string you can just do x[::-1], thus, you can write mirror as below

```
def mirror(x):
    return x + x[::-1]
```

Refer to https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html for details about slicing.